# Class Constructors and Elements

Tags: c++, class, struct

What would be the proper way to create the default and override constructors for the class Binary within the cpp file in this case?

```
binary.h
class Binary {
private:
    struct BinaryNode {
        int degree;
        BinaryNode* next;
        BinaryNode(int d, BinaryNode* n) : degree(d), next(n) {}
    };
    BinaryNode *firstTerm;
public: 
Binary() { firstTerm = nullptr; }
}
```

I'm not the best with cpp, and I cannot figure out how to write it without getting errors. 
I've been trying things similar to the following:

```
binary.cpp
Binary::BinaryNode(){

}
```

All I need to do is to access the degree and next within the cpp file. I know this can't be complex, but I haven't wrapped my head around accessing struct elements of a class yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want:

```
Binary::BinaryNode::BinaryNode()
{
    /* Constructor Body */
}
```

This means that this is the Constructor for struct BinaryNode within class Binary.

Comment: Is the current structure actually also a default structure? Does it only require an overload constructor within the cpp file?

Comment: @JRW2252 I'm not sure what you're asking. The above is called a default-constructor. You can declare it in the `.h` file and define it (like this answer does) in the `.cpp` file.

Answer (score 0):

use this..

Binary::BinaryNode::BinaryNode(int d, BinaryNode* n) : degree(d), next(n)
{

}